# Static Friction on a Circular Road

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

I was recently brushing up on my dynamics, when I saw the interpretation of how a car moves in a circular road. Apparently, the car can stay in a circle due to static friction acting inwards. But I don't seem to understand exactly why this force exists and where it originates. What kind of motion causes it to exist?

Comment: Moving in a circle is just a special case of turning the car, so you just have to explain how the friction of the tyres can turn the car. This is explained in my answer to [Direction of friction when a car turns](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87976/direction-of-friction-when-a-car-turns)